# Detect touch scroll up or down

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, touch

I need code same this for touch devices . help me please

```
$(window).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
    if (ScrollEnable) {
        if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
            console.log('Down');
        } else {
            console.log('Up');
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

and here is my touch code, But consul just take up i need find down for my website ! what can i do :|

```
$('body').on({
    'touchmove': function(e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.touches > 0 || e.originalEvent.touches > 0) {
            console.log('Down');
        } else {
            console.log('Up');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: http://hammerjs.github.io/

Comment: You need to detect `touch` events...not mouse events..

Comment: jQuery-Mobile is a **FRAMKEWORK** it is NOT "how to use jQuery for mobile.". Please read [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-mobile/info) before adding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use scroll event

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
var st = $(this).scrollTop();
if (st > lastScrollTop){
   // downscroll code
} else {
  // upscroll code
}
lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: Note that this is detecting that the window was scrolled, by any means. This will be perfect for many use cases. But alternatively, you may be looking only for *user-initiated* scrolling, e.g., if your app also does code-initiated scrolling such as element.scrollIntoView(). In which case you'll want to detect several individual events: DOMMouseScroll(firefox), mousewheel(chrome/most others), touchmove(mobile). Are there any others?

Answer (score 5):

```
var updated=0,st;
$('body').on({
    'touchmove': function(e) { 
    st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(st > updated) {
        console.log('down');
    }
    else {
        console.log('up');
    }
    updated = st;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I know my solution is a bit more generic - it is not dependend on any element, but it might help someone that has encountered the same problem as me.

```
var touchPos;

// store the touching position at the start of each touch
document.body.ontouchstart = function(e){
    touchPos = e.changedTouches[0].clientY;
}

// detect wether the "old" touchPos is 
// greater or smaller than the newTouchPos
document.body.ontouchmove = function(e){
    let newTouchPos = e.changedTouches[0].clientY;
    if(newTouchPos > touchPos) {
        console.log("finger moving down");
    }
    if(newTouchPos < touchPos) {
        console.log("finger moving up");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more responsive than the other solutions offered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I could (and tested) detect scroll down/up on mobile devices (android & ios, touch devices):

*(other events such as `scroll`, `mousewheel`, `DOMMouseScroll`, `nmousewheel` and `wheel` do not work on mobile devices)*

**jQuery:**

```js
let touchStartPosX = 0;
  // Detect Scroll Down and Up in mobile(android|ios)
  $(window).on('touchmove', (e) => {
    // Different devices give different values with different decimal percentages.
    const currentPageX = Math.round(e.originalEvent.touches[0].screenY);
    if (touchStartPosX === currentPageX) return;

    if (touchStartPosX - currentPageX > 0) {
      console.log("down");
    } else {
      console.log("up");
    }
    touchStartPosX = currentPageX;
  });
```

**Vanilla:**

```js
  let touchStartPosX = 0;
  window.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
    // Different devices give different values with different decimal percentages.
    const currentPageX = Math.round(e.changedTouches[0].screenY);
    if (touchStartPosX === currentPageX) return;

    if (touchStartPosX - currentPageX > 0) {
      console.log("down");
    } else {
      console.log("up");
    }
    touchStartPosX = currentPageX;
  });
```

Comment: in vanilla we have this error " Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'touches') "

Comment: @ehsanwwe
My bad, you're right, fixed, take a look. There is no `originalEvent` property in the vanilla event, so I fixed it and used the `changedTouches` property instead. Thanks

Comment: Hi, are you variables named correctly? It seems to me you're detecting Y scroll but the variable is called X? I just wanna make sure I'm not missing anything.

Answer (score -1):

This w3schools.com documentation would help you out http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_scroll.asp

```
$(document).on("scrollstop",function(){
  alert("Stopped scrolling!");
});
```